# Disable IE pop up blocker through Options class or DesiredCapabilities

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I know this can be done manually once by going to *Tools>Internet Options>Privacy* and unchecking **Turn on Pop-up Blocker**. The problem is if I run these tests on a different machine the tests related to pop up window will fail. Is there a way to accomplish this using `Options` or `DesireCapabilities` for `Internet Explorer`. I have tried with options

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { EnableNativeEvents = false };
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Dismiss;
```

I have tried

```
InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Accept;
```

But, did not work. Still blocks the pop up

[image]

Comment: can u try out with this... `ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);`... its for java...

Comment: For a similar requirement, I update the registry programmatically in the slave machines - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows    ; PopupMgr should be 0

Comment: @VivekSingh Sorry it did not work

Comment: @VinothS thanks. I was actually more interested in disabling programmatically

Comment: @Saifur , actually Vinoth was trying to say that you can update the registry programmatically (with c#)  in test initialize method.

Comment: @VinothS Thanks for the answer and clarification. But, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Import this - Microsoft.Win32

```
RegistryKey regKey = default(RegistryKey);
regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\New Windows", true);
regKey.SetValue("PopupMgr", 0);
regKey.Close();
```

Comment: Will try it mate and get back to you. Thanks!