# Selenium- internet explorer disable script debugging

Tags: windows, winapi, selenium, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Last couple of days I have been trying to figure out the ways to handle a few issues with `Selenium` and `IE` Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306871/disable-ie-pop-up-blocker-through-options-class-or-desiredcapabilities)

[image]

Today, I wanted to run all the `Selenium` tests against `IE9` but in the middle of the test, due to a `JavaScript` error the debugger popped up and all the tests started failing. Just an extra bit of information I tried using

```
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Dismiss;
```

which was not able to dismiss that debugger window.
[image]

I know I can manually do it by unchecking the debugger as follows. But, this is not a feasible solution since these tests can be executed in a lot of different machines.

**Is there a way to do these programatically with `DesireCapability` or `Options`? Or at least any commands for commandline?**

[image]

Comment: I am fairly sure this is a registry setting and as such you should be able to change it via your code. I found this old C/C# method with a quick google: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/232159-turn-off-script-debugger-programmatically\

Comment: @ratsstack Thanks for your reply. I am aware about the registry tweak. But, I do not not want to go that far if I do not have to